# Ошибка при загрузке .qml-файла: "ComboBoxStyle is not a type"

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml, qt6

Я взял код .qml-файла с [этого ответа](https://forum.qt.io/post/534219) и попробовал протестировать его, однако после запуска приложения появляется такой текст ошибки (приложение запускается, но с пустым окном):

```
qrc:/app.qml:17:16: ComboBoxStyle is not a type 
             style: ComboBoxStyle { 
                    ^
```

Вот код.

app.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 200
    title: "Simple ComboBox Example"

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        width: 200
        model: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
        currentIndex: 0 // Установка начального выбора (первая опция)

        // Стиль ComboBox
        style: ComboBoxStyle {
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering

            background: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 25
                border.width: 1
            }

            label: Label {
                anchors {
                    fill: parent
                    left: parent.left
                    leftMargin: 5
                }
                font.pixelSize: 12
                text: control.currentText
                verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QUrl url("qrc:/app.qml");

    QQuickView view(url);

    view.show();

    return QGuiApplication::exec();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(QtQmlTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Quick QuickControls2)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt::Core Qt::Gui Qt::Widgets Qt::Quick Qt::QuickControls2)

qt_add_resources(${PROJECT_NAME} "qml"
        PREFIX "/"
        BASE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
        FILES app.qml)
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Надо добавить импорт для стиля https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-comboboxstyle.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin теперь у меня ошибка "module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed ". Вообще это же для Qt-5. Может быть, для Qt-6 это не работает.

Comment: Теперь похоже это делается без ComboBoxStyle https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-customize.html#customizing-combobox